# Generating proxies with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have cleared my symfony2 application and now cannot run the application because cannot generate proxies for entities from the command line while a few have actually been generated by default.

I have tried to run the command below which usually did the trick in earlier versions of symfony/ doctrine:

```
php bin/console doctrine:ensure-production-settings --no-debug --env=prod
```

But this time I only get the following response:

```
Query Cache uses a non-persistent cache driver, Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache.
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
php bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug
```

How ever the  command you are trying

```
php bin/console doctrine:ensure-production-settings --no-debug --env=prod
```

is not for generating proxies, but for  verifying that Doctrine is properly configured for a production environment.

And to actually to make sure you are ready for production , you need to use one of the cache drivers mentioned [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#cache-drivers)
.

Comment: This worked thanks and even more for enlightening me on the command uses. I greatly appreciate this